# Cell height not getting set in list view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cell

I have a list view in a Xamarin forms app and one of my labels can have a really long set of text. The problem is the text just gets cut off and the height of the labels are never multi line.

Can I make it multiline?
Can I make the height be much higher?

Below is my code. I tried adjusting the height in several places but none of them are making the cell larger.

```
                //      each item; it must return a Cell derivative.)
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    // Create views with bindings for displaying each property.
                    Xamarin.Forms.Label nameLabel = new Xamarin.Forms.Label();
                    nameLabel.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.Label.TextProperty,
                        new Binding("Name", BindingMode.OneWay,
                        null, null, "{0}"));

                    Xamarin.Forms.Label yearLabel = new Xamarin.Forms.Label();
                    yearLabel.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.Label.TextProperty,
                        new Binding("Birthday", BindingMode.OneWay,
                            null, null, "FMI {0:yyyy}"));

                    Xamarin.Forms.Label componentLabel = new Xamarin.Forms.Label();
                    componentLabel.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.Label.TextProperty,
                        new Binding("Component", BindingMode.OneWay,
                            null, null, "Component: {0}"));

                    Xamarin.Forms.Label descriptionLabel = new Xamarin.Forms.Label();
                    descriptionLabel.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.Label.TextProperty,
                        new Binding("Description", BindingMode.OneWay,
                            null, null, "{0}"));
                    descriptionLabel.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

                    descriptionLabel.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.NoWrap;
                    descriptionLabel.HeightRequest = 256.0;
                    descriptionLabel.MinimumHeightRequest = 250.0;

                    BoxView boxView = new BoxView();
                    boxView.SetBinding(BoxView.ColorProperty, "SeverityColor");
                    boxView.MinimumHeightRequest = 100.0;
                    boxView.MinimumHeightRequest = 100.0;

                    // Return an assembled ViewCell.
                    return new ViewCell
                    {
                        View = new StackLayout
                        {
                            Padding = new Thickness(0, 2),
                            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                            HeightRequest = 155.0,
                            MinimumHeightRequest = 155.0,
                            Children =
                                {
                                    boxView,
                                    new StackLayout
                                    {
                                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                                        Spacing = 0,
                                        HeightRequest = 235.0,
                                        MinimumHeightRequest = 250.0,

                                        Children =
                                        {
                                            componentLabel,
                                            descriptionLabel
                                        }
                                   }
                                }
                        },Height = 250
                    };
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how ListView is defined. Sometime

```
listview.HasUnevenRows = true;
```

helps

[HasUnevenRows](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows/)

Comment: That is what I needed. My rows are all too large but that property was needed to honor the row height requests. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a strange behavior of multi line Labels placed in a StackLayout with Horizontal orientation.

Please see [my comment](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/261818/#Comment_261818) in Xamarin Forms forum.